# Experiencing Unsupported class file major version 61 error

Tags: android

I am experiencing the error, **Unsupported class file major version 61**, while building my application APK,
how can I fix the error?
below is the detailed info of the error.

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform activity-1.8.0.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\sakaf\AndroidStudioProjects\Thetech\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.8.0\4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca\activity-1.8.0.aar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\sakaf\AndroidStudioProjects\Thetech\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.8.0\4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca\activity-1.8.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 61. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

I was building an APK for testing my App which i expected to build successfully and generate apk to install to my phone

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're still using Jetifier? If your project no longer relies on dependencies that use the old android.support namespace, you should really be removing that altogether